# Error al imprimir por bluetooth desde el celular a impresora térmica. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Actualmente tengo un pequeño programa en angular que usa la API de Google Bluetooth para  conectarme a una impresora térmica POS.

En estos momentos tengo un problema, al ejecutar mi programa desde el computador funciona bien, pero si entro desde desde mi celular e imprimo tiene errores.

Este es mi código (Función con la que me conecto a la impresora e imprimo un ticket de prueba):

```
  connect(){
    this._navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    filters: [{
     services: ['000018f0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']
    }]
   })
   .then( device => {
     console.log(device)
     return device.gatt?.connect();
   })
   .then(server => {
     console.log("getting service - control");
     return server?.getPrimaryService('000018f0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
   })
   .then(service => {
     console.log("Getting characteristics");
     return service?.getCharacteristic('00002af1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
   })
   .then(characteristic => {
     let encoder = new TextEncoder();
     let text = encoder.encode(this.getTicket() + '\u000A\u000D');
     characteristic?.writeValue(text);
   })
   .catch( error => {
    console.error("Ocurrio un problema inesperado")
    console.log(error);
   })
 }
```

Función que me retorna el ticket:

```
getTicket(): string{
 let ticket = ""
 ticket += "Andrés Camilo Zapata Cardona \n"
 ticket += "=========================== \n"
 ticket += "Producto  Cantidad  Valor \n"
 ticket += "=========================== \n"
 ticket += "Leche       2  $2500 \n"
 ticket += "Huevos      3  $1200 \n"
 ticket += "Mantequilla 1  $4000 \n"
 ticket += "Café        1  $3000 \n"

 return ticket;
}
```

Así imprime desde el computador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y Así imprime desde el celular (tuve que llamar dos veces la función para imprimir):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado de text, el encode que se genera es igual tanto en web como movil.

```
72,111,108,97,32,10,32,68,101,109,111,115,116,114,97,99,105,195,179,110,10,13
```

Muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: es un error de codificación

Comment: Hola @Christian, Sabes como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: no soy experto en JS y menos en lo que tratas de hacer, considero que no es un problema difícil y tal vez pronto obtengas una respuesta, lo siento por no poder ayudar más.

Comment: Hubieras mostrado la impresión entera. De la impresión desde el celular.

Comment: Hola @Alfredo Maussa, gracias por responder, eso que muestro en la foto es todo lo que imprime

Comment: Intente poner un console.log en `characteristic?.writeValue(text);`. Preferiblemente que muestre text como un array de hexadecimales. Así será posible confirmar lo que dice  @Christian al comparar el hex. No es necesario enviarla a la impresora, puedes comentar esa línea de código.

Comment: Hola @Alfredo, acabo de poner el resultado en la pregunta, pero tanto en web como móvil es el mismo resultado :/

Comment: @AndrésGutiérrez Si aún no solucionas, al menos probar con 2 líneas (que incluya caracteres 'endline' y 'newline') y con los caracteres especiales (=, $ y tildes... andrés, café), si hay algún error de condificación no se verá con "Hola" sino con esos caracteres poco comunes.